# nested list inlisp

Tags: list, lisp

I have an excercise to get a nested list and replace each word with a "funny" word. We got a declaration of what is "funny" word.

I  wrote this code

```
(defun funny_nestes (nested_l)
  (cond ((null nested_l) "")
        ((atom (car nested_l))
         (cons (funnyw (car nested_l))
               (funny_nestes (cdr nested_l))))
        (t (cons (funny_nestes (car nested_l))
                 (funny_nestes (cdr nested_l))))))
```

when 'funnyw' is the function that return the "funny" word.

If I run

```
(FUNNY_NESTES '(ata (she lamadta be JCT) oved be NDS))
```

I get

```
("AbATAbA " ("SHEbE " "LAbAMAbADTAbA " "BEbE " "JCT " . "")
 "ObOVEbED " "BEbE " "NDS " . "")
```

and I want to get

```
(AbATAb (SHEbE LAbAMAbADTAbA  BEbE  JCT) ObOVEbED  BEbE  NDS )
```

How can I fix it? And how can i do it with lambda?

Answer (score 0):

'And how can i do it with lambda?' What does it mean 'do with lambda'?

Why is there an empty string in your code?

If you want symbols instead of strings, then you need to convert the strings to symbols.

Comment: the empty string is for the base case of the recursive

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab in the dark, assuming this is what is being asked:

```
(defun replace-with-gibberish (modifier words)
  (cond
    ((null words) nil)
    ((consp (car words))
     (cons (replace-with-gibberish modifier (car words))
           (replace-with-gibberish modifier (cdr words))))
    (t (cons (funcall modifier (car words))
             (replace-with-gibberish modifier (cdr words))))))

(replace-with-gibberish
 #'(lambda (x)
     (intern
      (coerce
       (mapcan #'list
               (coerce (symbol-name x) 'list)
               (coerce
                (make-string
                 (length (symbol-name x))
                 :initial-element #\b) 'list)) 'string)))
 '(ata (she lamadta be JCT) oved be NDS))
```

Which I could infer from the result you show. However, you should be aware of that if you want to get rid of the pipes surrounding the symbols - you would need to generate gibberish names for symbols using upper-case letter. (By default symbol names are upper case, and if they need to contain lower-case letters, they need to be escaped).

The problem with your question is that you basically got the function that you posted right, but the one that you didn't posted seems to be wrong (the funnyw). I went ahead and assumed that you wanted to replace it with just any function - that's why the example.